# How to define a boolean API RESTful?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I have to define an API that answers whether a resource with given ID can be created, like

> Can I (caller) create this resource with id=resource1 ?

The possible responses could be

- 401 - The caller is not authenticated
- 403 - The caller is authenticated but not authorized to perform this check
- 200 - Yes, you can create a resource with id=resource1
- ...

Now my questions are

1. How can I model the API? 
   Will, `GET /resources/resource1` be a good choice?
2. What HTTP codes will suite for responses like, 
   (a) this resource id is already taken, (b) you don't have permission to create this particular id (but only few other ids), (c) you can create this id.

Answer (score 6):

An example in github may help you.

The api designed for checking if a user is following another user:

`GET /user/following/:username`

The deal information is presented in [github's api document](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/#check-if-you-are-following-a-user)

For your question1, I think you can implement like this:

`GET /resource/existence/:resource_id`

For question2, you may also take a look at [github's client errors](https://developer.github.com/v3/#client-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be better to just try and create the resource with a **POST**? and let your implementation handle the response from there? In which case your responses could be:

a) 409: Conflict
b) 401: Unauthorized
c) 200: OK

If that's not possible, then I guess your payload response from a **GET** can contain the result. Something as simple as:

**true**: You can create the resource
**false**: You cannot create the resource

Comment: Just keep in mind that a 409 is more commonly used for Optimistic Locking errors such as somebody else modified the resource and therefore your update is outdate.

Comment: Thanks @BernieLenz - Agree with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to check the permissions regarding the addition, you should use a different resource than the one that actually added the element. IMO something like `/permissions/{elementName}?id=theid` or `/permissions/{elementName}/{operationName}?id=theid`. Accessing it with method `GET` would suit.

Using the same resource would be a bit "messy" I think since I would expect the method `GET` on `/resources/resource1` to actually return the content of the element with identifier `ressource1`.

Regarding the response, I would see this:

- `401` if the user isn't authentication and the permission resource requires an authentication.
- `204` if the current user is allowed to add an element with the specified identifier. I don't think that you need a response payload in this case.
- Regarding the case when the user isn't allowed to add an element with the provided identifier, I think the status code `403` (`Forbidden`) suits. Perhaps a status code `400` could also match if you consider that the user provides a wrong content. In this case some hints about the error (identifier value not allowed) should be returned within the response payload.

For me, the status code `409` (`Conflict`) is more when implementing optimistic locking, i.e. concurrent accesses (updates) on the same element.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry